# How to be sure that you are not tracked with anti-theft software or similar when using tab previously owned by someone?

Tags: samsung, privacy, anti-theft

I have seen the amount of pictures and personal data an anti-theft software can dig on person using a stolen phone. How can one make sure that he is not tracked through similar software when using a previously owned tab/phone? I understand that a factory reset is not enough in most cases.

Comment: Nothing personal, as far as I know, but I hope this is very difficult -- I had a tablet stolen a few months ago, and it stayed "not located" on Google Device Manager for a couple months, then just dropped off.

Comment: In all honesty, if you buy used, you get used. In any object, be it computers, cars, furniture, tickets, etc. you always have a measure of "Buyer Beware" going on. As for your tablet, flash a fresh ROM on it. Anything short of that - no guarantees, maybe not even then.

Comment: My folks bought the tab. I was thinking of flashing a new ROM on it. Just wanted to make sure what is enough. I think the tape stays on the cameras even after the flash...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I understand that a factory reset is not enough in most cases.

A factory reset is usually enough if performed through Settings, which removes Factory Reset Protection from the device (a reset from Recovery does not do this).  This will also unlink Android Device Manager and remove most other tracking tools.

If you are concerned about apps that may have been integrated into the system image, then yes you should flash a custom recovery and then a ROM (selecting the wipe option).  Unless there is a malicious bootloader installed (unlikely) then this will more than suffice.  You might also want do delete anything from `/sdcard` and format any external SD cards just to ensure that no malicious files are left there that you might accidentally use.

Comment: I did as you suggested and feel more secure already. The custom recovery provided an option to format the whole device. Thanks!